# How to paste rows on the basis of another column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, paste

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
df = data.frame(ID = c("Text 1.1", "Text 1.2", "Text 1.3", "Text 1.4", "Text 2.1", "Text 2.2", "Text 2.3"), Text = c("Hello", "Hello World", "World", "Ciao", "Ciao Ciao", "SO will fix it", "World  is great"))

       ID            Text
1 Text 1.1           Hello
2 Text 1.2     Hello World
3 Text 1.3           World
4 Text 1.4            Ciao
5 Text 2.1       Ciao Ciao
6 Text 2.2  SO will fix it
7 Text 2.3 World  is great
```

I would like to achieve this:

```
       ID            Text
1 Text 1           Hello Hello World  World  Ciao
2 Text 2       Ciao Ciao SO will fix it World  is great
```

Basically, I would like to paste the text in the second column for every `1.1,...,1.n`; `2.1,...,2.n`, etc.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work:

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(tidyr)
> df %>% separate(col = ID, into = c('ID','Sub-ID'), sep = '\\.') %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(Text = paste0(Text, collapse = ' '))
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  ID     Text                                    
  <chr>  <chr>                                   
1 Text 1 Hello Hello World World Ciao            
2 Text 2 Ciao Ciao SO will fix it World  is great
>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Both answers work very well. As a personal policy, I tend to reward the answer whose author has less reputation. That's why I awarded the correct answer to the second attempt.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  # extract everything before the "." in ID
  mutate(group = str_extract(ID, ".*(?=\\.)")) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  # paste together
  summarize(Text = paste(Text, collapse = " "))
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   group  Text                                    
#   <chr>  <chr>                                   
# 1 Text 1 Hello Hello World World Ciao            
# 2 Text 2 Ciao Ciao SO will fix it World  is great
```